# Styling asp textboxes inside a list?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

So I'm styling an HTML list with in my CSS like so:

```
.ulClaims li

{
   font-weight: bold; 
   color: #5c6467;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

I have asp:textboxes in some of my '**li**' tags.  Is there anyway I can style them in my .ulClaims class to make things simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS definition is only applying the style to the `li`s that are descendants of `.ulClaims`. To style the "textboxes" use something akin to:

```
.ulClaims li input[type="text"] { /* ... definitions ... */ }
.ulClaims li textarea { /* ... definitions ... */ }
```

This will directly target any `input type="text"` or `textarea` that is a descendant of `.ulClaims li`.